# Using Python Regular Expression in Django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have an web address:

http://www.example.com/org/companyA

I want to be able to pass CompanyA to a view using regular expressions.

This is what I have:

```
(r'^org/?P<company_name>\w+/$',"orgman.views.orgman")
```

and it doesn't match.

Ideally all URL's that look like example.com/org/X would pass x to the view.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to wrap the group name in parentheses. The syntax for named groups is `(?P<name>regex)`, not `?P<name>regex`.  Also, if you don't want to require a trailing slash, you should make it optional.

It's easy to test regular expression matching with the Python interpreter, for example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^org/?P<company_name>\w+/$', 'org/companyA')
>>> re.match(r'^org/(?P<company_name>\w+)/?$', 'org/companyA')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10049c378>
>>> re.match(r'^org/(?P<company_name>\w+)/?$', 'org/companyA').groupdict()
{'company_name': 'companyA'}
```

Comment: This is awesome.  I was looking for something like this online!

Answer (score 2):

Your regex isn't valid.  It should probably look like

```
r'^org/(?P<company_name>\w+)/$'
```

Answer (score 1):

It should look more like `r'^org/(?P<company_name>\w+)'`

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'^org/(?P<company_name>\w+)')
>>> r.match('org/companyA').groups()
('companyA',)
```